# Unselect tabs in tab navigator js

Tags: javascript, html, tabs

This tab navigator doesnt have any tab selected in the beginning so neither tab1 or tab2's content are displayed until you click in one fo them, I have a dropdown outside of it, i want this tab navigator to go back when neither tabs were selected and their content displayed when you change something in the dropdown. How can I do that in the onchange function of the dropdown. I have other tabs navigator in the page so it need to be something that affects only this one.

```
    <div>
        <select id="DropDown1">
            <option selected value="0">0</option>
            <option value="2">1</option>
        </select>
    </div>


     <div class="well well-large">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills" id = "tab_n">
            <li><a href="#Tab1" data-toggle="tab">Tab1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Tab2" data-toggle="tab">Tab2</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane" id="Tab1">
                //content
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="Tab2">
                //content
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


<script>
       $('#DropDown1').on('change', function () {
            //First Try             
            tab_n.children[0].className = tab_n.children[0].className.replace(" active", "");
            tab_nav.children[1].className = tab_nav.children[1].className.replace(" active", "");

            //Second try
            $('a.nav-pills a[href="#Tab1"]').tab('hide');
            $('a.nav-pills a[href="#Tab2"]').tab('hide');

            //third try,this one hid the content permanently and didnt unselect the tab
            $('#Tab1').hide();
            $('#Tab2').hide();
         });    
    <script>
```

I read about this here but didnt work:
http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp

Comment: Can't see a dropdown, a script, no nothing that shows what you tried.

Comment: Already edited with what i tried.